# Problem with bibliography display

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have some issues with the bibliography, it was working on my document, until one day it disappeared actually I had a problem with the numbering the mentionning was not in the right order, I wanted to fix this and I end up with nothing xD.

So this is how I do I begin with these lines

```latex
\usepackage[backend=biber,maxnames=12,style=numeric,sorting=ydnt,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{lib.bib}
```

of course `lib.bib` is in the same folder and to print the bib I simply use `\printbibliography`.

Comment: Welcome. Do you run biber as well?

Comment: Delete the `.aux`, `.bbl` and `.bcf` file from your document directory. Then run the full compilation cycle LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (where "LaTeX" can be your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...; you can read about why this cycle is necessary in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864). Make sure that the LaTeX runs do not produce any errors. If there are errors, fix them and repeat the procedure (delete the temporary files and recompile with the full cycle). ...

Comment: ... If that does not help, please prepare a compilable example document that shows what you are doing (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) and add the full contents of the `.blg` file to your question.

Comment: Thanks guys its working now but I still have the order problem, I'd like to number my bibliography in order of appearance.
Do u have a trick for that ? TY

Comment: `sorting=none,` instead of `sorting=ydnt,`.

Comment: When i do that my bibliography disappears

Comment: You will have to run LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX again for the changes to apply.

Comment: Thanks ! It's working now

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/194481)

Comment: It looks like you have two different accounts.  These can be merged by the moderators.